# LLVM IR Function with an array parameter

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api, llvm-ir

I want to generate LLVM IR code from two basic c++ functions which are like below.

```
int newFun2(int x){
    int z = x + x;
    return z;
}

int newFun(int *y){
    int first = y[3]; //How to define it using the LLVM API?
    int num = newFun2(first);
    return num;
}
```

My problem is to get an index of the array parameter using the LLVM API. Any ideas ?
Thank you so much

EDITTED

**This is my code using the API:**

```
llvm::LLVMContext &context = llvm::getGlobalContext();
llvm::Module *module = new llvm::Module("AST", context);
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder(context);

//newFun2
llvm::FunctionType *newFunc2Type = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), builder.getInt32Ty(), false);
llvm::Function *newFunc2 = llvm::Function::Create(newFunc2Type, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "newFun2", module);

llvm::Function::arg_iterator argsFun2 = newFunc2->arg_begin();
llvm::Value* x = argsFun2++;
x->setName("x");

llvm::BasicBlock* block = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "entry", newFunc2);
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder2(block);

llvm::Value* tmp = builder2.CreateBinOp(llvm::Instruction::Add,
                                 x, x, "tmp");

builder2.CreateRet(tmp);

//newFun
llvm::FunctionType *newFuncType = llvm::FunctionType::get(builder.getInt32Ty(), builder.getInt32Ty()->getPointerTo(), false);
llvm::Function *newFunc = llvm::Function::Create(newFuncType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, "newFun", module);

llvm::BasicBlock* block2 = llvm::BasicBlock::Create(context, "entry", newFunc);
llvm::IRBuilder<> builder3(block2);

module->dump();
```

**And this is the LLVM IR that is generated :**

```
; ModuleID = 'AST'

define i32 @newFun2(i32 %x) {
entry:
  %tmp = add i32 %x, %x
  ret i32 %tmp
}

define i32 @newFun(i32*) {
entry:
}
```

I am stuck on the body of newFun because of the array access.

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Are you unsure about how the generated IR should look like? Or do you understand how it should look like, but need help with the API calls to generate it? Or are you using the Clang frontend and can't find the array index in the AST? Or maybe it's something else entirely...

Comment: hi, I just updated my post with what I have until now. I am stuck on the body of the newFun. I don't know the API call to generate the array access part for me. Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that you first need to understand how the IR should look like. It can be done by peering into [the language specification](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html) or by [using Clang to compile the C code into IR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148890/how-to-make-clang-compile-to-llvm-ir) and taking a look at the result.

In any case, the way to access an array element at a given index is either with [extractvalue](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#extractvalue-instruction) (which only accepts constant indices) or with a [gep](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#getelementptr-instruction). Both of these have corresponding constructors / factory methods and `IRBuilder` methods to construct them, for example

```
builder.CreateExtractValue(y, 3);
```

Creating a gep is a little more complicated; I recommend taking a look at [the gep guide](http://llvm.org/docs/GetElementPtr.html).

However, a good way to see how to call the LLVM API to create the desired IR is to use `llc` (one of the LLVM command-line tools) to generate a source file with those calls itself from an IR file, see these two related questions:

- [Possible to auto-generate llvm c++ api code from LLVM-IR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9836321/possible-to-auto-generate-llvm-c-api-code-from-llvm-ir)
- [Generate LLVM C++ API code as backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751403/generate-llvm-c-api-code-as-backend)

Comment: thank you so much, that is what I was looking for. llc is really a great way to understand the api as you have suggested.